# Как остановить таймер при условии?

Tags: angular2, rxjs, observer

Использую библиотеку RxJS для создания пинг запроса на сервер каждые 3 секунды:

```
this.timerStep2Step2 = Observable.timer(3000, 3000).takeUntil(Observable.timer(60000))
      .flatMap(() => {
        return this.requestMethods.requestPassportData(data);
      })
      .subscribe((response) => {
       if (response == 1) {
           this.timerStep2Step2.unsubscribe();
       }
})
```

Я пытаюсь остановить таймер (отписаться) при условии что ответ от сервера равен:

```
if (response == 1) {// Unsibscribe}
```

Эта схема работает, но она мне не нравится своей громоздкостью. Если более удачная реализация в RXJS?

Моя реализация выглядит таким образом:

```
function a() {

const i = Rx.Observable.interval(1000);
const source = Rx.Observable.of(0);

const example = source.switchMap(event => {
    return i
}).takeWhile(val => {
 return val < 10;
})
  .finally(()  => alert('Done'));
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));

}

a();
a();
a();
```

При вызове трех раз функцию `a()` в консоли я вижу что создаются 3 обсервер-таймера, таким образом `switchMap` почему не отменяет предыдущий вызов `a()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть несколько операторов для этого, вы здесь неправильно используете `takeUntil`, `takeUntil` - как раз таки один из операторов, который подписан на какой-то поток и слушает `next` событие, здесь вы зачем то передаете `timer(60000)`, но в вашей проблеме я вижу, что нужно отписаться, как только `response = 1`:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { timer } from 'rxjs/observable/timer';
import { switchMapTo } from 'rxjs/operators/switchMapTo';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators/takeUntil';

const destroy$ = new Subject<void>();

timer(3000, 3000).pipe(
    switchMapTo(this.requestMethods.requestPassportData(data)),
    takeUntil(destroy$)
).subscribe((response) => {
    if (response !== 1) {
        return;
    }

    destroy$.next();
    destroy$.complete();
});
```

Заметьте, что `takeUntil` нужно использовать после `switchMap`, а не перед, так как `switchMap` создает новый поток, у вас в примере `flatMap` - он уже устарел как больше года с выходом `rxjs >= 5.5`.

Второй вариант с использованием `takeWhile`:

```
import { timer } from 'rxjs/observable/timer';
import { switchMapTo } from 'rxjs/operators/switchMapTo';
import { takeWhile } from 'rxjs/operators/takeWhile';

let shouldTake = true;

timer(3000, 3000).pipe(
    switchMapTo(this.requestMethods.requestPassportData(data)),
    takeWhile(() => shouldTake)
).subscribe((response) => {
    if (response !== 1) {
        return;
    }

    shouldTake = false;
});
```

`takeWhile` имеет свои подводные камни - он не закрывает поток, в отличии от `takeUntil`.

Третий вариант и самый элегантный с использованием `filter` и `take`:

```
import { timer } from 'rxjs/observable/timer';
import { switchMapTo } from 'rxjs/operators/switchMapTo';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators/take';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators/filter';

timer(3000, 3000).pipe(
    switchMapTo(this.requestMethods.requestPassportData(data)),
    filter((response) => response === 1),
    take(1)
).subscribe((response) => {
    console.log(response)
});
```

`take` аргументом принимает количество событий, которые нужно сгенерировать, к тому же этот оператор сам завершает поток и отписывается, то есть не нужно помещать `Subscription` в переменную и далее где-то писать `unsubscribe`, `take(n)` - все сделает за вас сам.

Comment: Поосмотрите пожалуйста мой вопрос еще раз - мою реализацию

Comment: @Jony, я указал в ответе `takeWhile имеет свои подводные камни`, этот оператор ведет себя по разному в разных ситуациях, я вам как пример привел, чтобы вы знали о его существовании, возможно вам было бы интересно почитать о нем документацию, но последний пример самый лучший и как раз то, что вам нужно. `takeWhile` с щедулерами (scheduler) ведет себя вообще по другому и может привести к утечкам памяти, будьте осторожны!

Comment: Я прочитал Ваш комментарий - даже если я его исключу - то  switchMap все равно не останавливает предыдущий запущенный поток

Comment: В моем случае takeWhile работает правильно. А вот switchMap - нет

Comment: используйте `filter + take`

Comment: `switchMap` делает complete для предыдущего Observable

Comment: ` filter + take` не останавливает таймер. Мне нужно при каждом вызове останавливать таймер и начинать все заново

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/748o0k91/2/

Comment: стоп, у вас первый вопрос был с таймером и отпиской и вопрос звучал `Если более удачная реализация в RXJS?`, вы на него получили ответ, теперь вы опять перепрыгнули вообще на другую тему с использованием интервала

Comment: Я вам ответ обязательно приму - просто я предложил свое решение. Как я знаю switchMap автоматически отписывается при повтороном вызове. Все остальное как в впоросе

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83518/discussion-between-jony-and-overthesanity).